# Ruby retry incorrect user input

Tags: ruby

I need to retry incorrect user input but my piece of code doesn't work

```
def parse_param
begin 
  option = gets.chomp
  option = option.to_i
rescue 
  retry if option > 6
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

The `rescue` section will only be entered if an exception occurs in the `begin` block (see the docs for [Exception Handling](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html)).

Since you don't raise any exception yourself and the remaining code doesn't raise one either, the `rescue` section is not executed.

You *could* manually raise an exception this way: (just for demonstation purposes)

```
def parse_param
  begin 
    option = gets.chomp
    option = option.to_i
    raise if option > 6
    option
  rescue 
    retry
  end
end
```

However, raising an exception just to rescue it right-away is overly complicated. Also, an exception should be used for exceptional situations, i.e. something unexpected that your code cannot properly handle and which should be escalated to the caller.

For normal control flow, you could instead use a simple [`loop`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) along with [`break`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement), e.g.:

```
def parse_param
  loop do
    option = gets.chomp.to_i
    break option unless option > 6
  end
end
```

Ruby also has a [`redo`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-redo+Statement) statement which can be used to re-run the current iteration: (although it's rarely seen)

```
def parse_param
  loop do
    option = gets.chomp.to_i
    redo if option > 6
    break option
  end
end
```

Comment: @Stefan thanks a lot, your are right about raising error. One more thing. Is there any way to write this method and be able to use the result of it? I know I could use this code without defining method but I'm curious if there is any chance to use method result.

Comment: @mila002 the above methods return the input, so you can assign the result to a variable, e.g. `input = parse_param`.

Comment: @Stefan, thanks! New skills acquired :)

Answer (score 2):

The [answer of Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76613426/3982562) already explains why your current solution does not work. I just wanted to add an additional option.

Instead of doing a loop with `loop`, you could use [`while`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-while+Loop) or [`until`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-until+Loop).

```
def parse_param
  option = gets.chomp.to_i while !option || option > 6
  option
end
```

Note that we need `!option` as an additional check, since the initial value of `option` is `nil` on the first check.